# Flutter Firebase [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am building a Flutter app with Firebase as backend.

I register new users with that code :

```
final newUser = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: motDePasse1);
```

and directly after I call the current user with that code:

```
final user = await auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print("loggedInUser est ${loggedInUser.email}");
      }
```

The print shows the email of the user I just registered. It seems OK.

But, when the new user is registered, the app redirects the user to a new page that tries to read data in cloud firestore. There I receive the error

> [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

What's strange is that when I connect the same user with same credentials with that code:

```
await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      user = auth.currentUser!;
```

the app redirects to the same page and calls the same firestore data and there it works without any problem.

I think there is may be a sync problem between the update of the rules of firestore and firebase authentication that makes that when the page calls firestore data, the new user is not yet known by firestore...

```
The rules of Firestore is very simple:
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help !